# Adding a row title to a csv created with PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have PHP creating a CSV file for myself, however I'm looking to see if it's possible to create a row with titles (Latitude and longitude) on the files creation, but not in subsequent updates of the file.

```
    <?php
    $myFile = "locationlog";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fh, str_replace( array( 'lat=', '&lon=' ), array( '', ',' ), file_get_contents('php://input')));
    fclose($fh);
    echo "<html><head /><body><iframe src=\"$myFile\" style=\"height:100%; width:100%;\"></iframe></body></html>"

?>
```

This code creates a file like this:

```
55.0203786,-7.1819549
55.0204016,-7.1819482
55.0204016,-7.1819482
55.0203927,-7.1819593
55.0203927,-7.1819593
```

but I'm looking for it to create a file like this:

```
Latitude,Longitude
55.0203786,-7.1819549
55.0204016,-7.1819482
55.0204016,-7.1819482
55.0203927,-7.1819593
55.0203927,-7.1819593
```

I've tried manually putting the titles in, but it seems to stop the PHP script from updating the file again.

EDIT:

I've tried using the filesize method.

```
<?php
    $myFile = "locationlog";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
    if(filesize($file) == 0) { fwrite($fh, "Latitude,Longitude\r\n"); }
    elseif(filesize($file) > 0){
        fwrite($fh, str_replace( array( 'lat=', '&lon=' ), array( '', ',' ), file_get_contents('php://input')));
    }
    fclose($fh);
    echo "<html><head /><body><iframe src=\"$myFile\" style=\"height:100%; width:100%;\"></iframe></body></html>"

?>
```

It seems to have the opposite effect, showing this as the result:

```
Latitude,Longitude

Latitude,Longitude

Latitude,Longitude

Latitude,Longitude
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong.

EDIT 2:

I figured it out eventually. Thanks for the help! Here's the script, in case anyone needs it in the future.

```
<?php
    $myFile = "locationlog";
    if(filesize(locationlog) == 0) { 
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "Latitude,Longitude");
    }
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fh, str_replace( array( 'lat=', '&lon=' ), array( '', ',' ), file_get_contents('php://input')));
    fclose($fh);
    echo "<html><head /><body><iframe src=\"$myFile\" style=\"height:100%; width:100%;\"></iframe></body></html>"

?>
```

Comment: Make sure you set the mode of the file correctly, so the PHP process can edit the file.  As the owner will be different if you create your own file to put the initial headers in.

Comment: Worth mentioning [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)?

Comment: You can either check if the file exists before you attempt to open it for append, and add the headers if it does not.  Or open it as you are doing and check the file position.  eg. `if (ftell($myFile) == 0) { fwrite($fh, "Latitude,Longitude\r\n"); }`

Comment: `if(filesize($file) == 0) ....`

Comment: @Orbling: `ftell` does not work like that in append-only streams (which is a shame, it was my first guess too :) )

Comment: I've tried using file size.

`<?php
    $myFile = "locationlog";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
    if(filesize($file) == 0) { fwrite($fh, "Latitude,Longitude\r\n"); }
    elseif(filesize($file) > 0){
        fwrite($fh, str_replace( array( 'lat=', '&lon=' ), array( '', ',' ), file_get_contents('php://input')));
    }
    fclose($fh);
    echo "<html><head /><body><iframe src=\"$myFile\" style=\"height:100%; width:100%;\"></iframe></body></html>"

?>`

But it seems to have the opposite effect. It keeps showing the title and no data now.

Comment: @user2382925: Update your question, if you have a load more information to list.

Comment: @Wrikken: That's quite annoying, what does `ftell()` return at that point then, an error?  Seems odd behaviour as the file pointer must logically be at the beginning. :-/

Comment: @Wrikken: The intention seems to be the offset from the initial position, which is understandable, though a bit inconsistent.  Though it might be a bit situation/platform dependent judging by the comments, hence being defined as undefined.

Comment: @user2382925: With regard to your edit - you do not need the else if, that other line should happen every time, hence take it out of the if completely.

Comment: @Orbling: yes, it's a shame, most likely it has to do with multiple connections being able to write to that file in append mode (I can start 2 PHP processes writing to that file without any locking problems under Debian at least).

Answer (score 1):

after

```
fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
```

add

```
fwrite($fh, "Latitude,Longitude\r\n");
```

Comment: That would add it everytime.

Comment: The user mentioned `create a row with titles (Latitude and longitude) on the files creation, but not in subsequent updates of the file`. Update your answer with a [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) check.